# Replacing data based on corresponding rows

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   code  country              iso_o iso_d
   <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>
 1 ABW   Aruba                ABW   ABW  
 2 AFG   Afghanistan          ABW   AFG  
 3 AGO   Angola               ABW   AGO  
 4 AIA   Anguilla             ABW   AIA  
 5 ALB   Albania              ABW   ALB  
 6 AND   Andorra              ABW   AND  
 7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  ABW   ANT  
 8 ARE   United Arab Emirates ABW   ARE  
 9 ARG   Argentina            ABW   ARG  
10 ARM   Armenia              ABW   ARM
```

I need code for the first four variables in the picture: `code`, `country`, `iso_o` and `iso_d`. The variable `country` contains the country names and variable `code` contains the country codes. They are corresponding. If the information in the column iso_o matches the information in code, I want the that cell in iso_o to take the country name that corresponds to the code. Thanks in advance.

What I'm expecting:

If code = ABW and it's corresponding country is Aruba, I want iso_o and iso_d to say Aruba wherever there is ABW

Here's the data:

```
structure(list(code = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", 
"ANT", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM"), country = c("Aruba", "Afghanistan", 
"Angola", "Anguilla", "Albania", "Andorra", "Netherland Antilles", 
"United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia"), iso_o = c("ABW", 
"ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW"
), iso_d = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT", 
"ARE", "ARG", "ARM")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please run `dput(YOUR_DATA[1:8, 1:4])` and paste the output into the body of your question. That will let us try things on a subset of your data, formats and all, which is much easier than working from an image.

Comment: How is your code supposed to know that `ABW` is the correct code for `Aruba`?

Answer (score 0):

A little kludgey but:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df %>% select(iso_o = code, iso_o2 = country)) %>%
  select(code, country, iso_o2, iso_d) %>%
  rename(iso_o = iso_o2)
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(iso_o)`
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   code  country              iso_o iso_d
   <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>
 1 ABW   Aruba                Aruba ABW  
 2 AFG   Afghanistan          Aruba AFG  
 3 AGO   Angola               Aruba AGO  
 4 AIA   Anguilla             Aruba AIA  
 5 ALB   Albania              Aruba ALB  
 6 AND   Andorra              Aruba AND  
 7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  Aruba ANT  
 8 ARE   United Arab Emirates Aruba ARE  
 9 ARG   Argentina            Aruba ARG  
10 ARM   Armenia              Aruba ARM
```

Answer (score 0):

There is ambiguity in your question and it's not exactly clear what it is you want the output to look like. I have interpreted "If the information in the column iso_o matches the information in code, I want the that cell in iso_o to take the country name" to mean you only want to modify the row that meets that criteria. You could try `which()`. In this example, df is your data:

```
df[which(df[,1] == df[,3]),3] <- df[which(df[,1] == df[,3]),2]
```

This looks for rows `which` have matching values in the "code" and "iso_o" columns and if `TRUE`, the value from the "country" column is added to the "iso_o" column for that row. However, later in your question you state you want both "iso_o" and "iso_d" columns modified, in which case use:

```
df[which(df[,1] == df[,3]),3:4] <- df[which(df[,1] == df[,3]),2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible approaches to this problem; in addition to the answers already provided, do any of these solutions work for your use-case?

Solutions based on the [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df <- structure(list(code = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND",  "ANT", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM"), country = c("Aruba", "Afghanistan",  "Angola", "Anguilla", "Albania", "Andorra", "Netherland Antilles",  "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia"), iso_o = c("ABW",  "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW" ), iso_d = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT",  "ARE", "ARG", "ARM")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    code  country              iso_o iso_d
#>    <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>
#>  1 ABW   Aruba                ABW   ABW  
#>  2 AFG   Afghanistan          ABW   AFG  
#>  3 AGO   Angola               ABW   AGO  
#>  4 AIA   Anguilla             ABW   AIA  
#>  5 ALB   Albania              ABW   ALB  
#>  6 AND   Andorra              ABW   AND  
#>  7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  ABW   ANT  
#>  8 ARE   United Arab Emirates ABW   ARE  
#>  9 ARG   Argentina            ABW   ARG  
#> 10 ARM   Armenia              ABW   ARM

# create a "lookup" named vector
lookup <- df %>%
  pull(country) %>%
  setNames(df$code)
lookup
#>                    ABW                    AFG                    AGO 
#>                "Aruba"          "Afghanistan"               "Angola" 
#>                    AIA                    ALB                    AND 
#>             "Anguilla"              "Albania"              "Andorra" 
#>                    ANT                    ARE                    ARG 
#>  "Netherland Antilles" "United Arab Emirates"            "Argentina" 
#>                    ARM 
#>              "Armenia"

# using dplyr recode and named vector
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("iso"),
                ~recode(.x, !!!lookup)))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    code  country              iso_o iso_d               
#>    <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>               
#>  1 ABW   Aruba                Aruba Aruba               
#>  2 AFG   Afghanistan          Aruba Afghanistan         
#>  3 AGO   Angola               Aruba Angola              
#>  4 AIA   Anguilla             Aruba Anguilla            
#>  5 ALB   Albania              Aruba Albania             
#>  6 AND   Andorra              Aruba Andorra             
#>  7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  Aruba Netherland Antilles 
#>  8 ARE   United Arab Emirates Aruba United Arab Emirates
#>  9 ARG   Argentina            Aruba Argentina           
#> 10 ARM   Armenia              Aruba Armenia

# using dplyr coalesce and named vector
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("iso"),
                ~coalesce(lookup[ .x ], .x)))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    code  country              iso_o iso_d               
#>    <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>               
#>  1 ABW   Aruba                Aruba Aruba               
#>  2 AFG   Afghanistan          Aruba Afghanistan         
#>  3 AGO   Angola               Aruba Angola              
#>  4 AIA   Anguilla             Aruba Anguilla            
#>  5 ALB   Albania              Aruba Albania             
#>  6 AND   Andorra              Aruba Andorra             
#>  7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  Aruba Netherland Antilles 
#>  8 ARE   United Arab Emirates Aruba United Arab Emirates
#>  9 ARG   Argentina            Aruba Argentina           
#> 10 ARM   Armenia              Aruba Armenia

# using purrr modify_if and named vector
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("iso"),
                ~modify_if(.x, .x %in% df$code,
                           ~ lookup[.x])))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    code  country              iso_o iso_d               
#>    <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>               
#>  1 ABW   Aruba                Aruba Aruba               
#>  2 AFG   Afghanistan          Aruba Afghanistan         
#>  3 AGO   Angola               Aruba Angola              
#>  4 AIA   Anguilla             Aruba Anguilla            
#>  5 ALB   Albania              Aruba Albania             
#>  6 AND   Andorra              Aruba Andorra             
#>  7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  Aruba Netherland Antilles 
#>  8 ARE   United Arab Emirates Aruba United Arab Emirates
#>  9 ARG   Argentina            Aruba Argentina           
#> 10 ARM   Armenia              Aruba Armenia

# using stringr str_replace_all and named vector
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(iso_d = str_replace_all(iso_d, lookup),
         iso_o = str_replace_all(iso_o, lookup))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    code  country              iso_o iso_d               
#>    <chr> <chr>                <chr> <chr>               
#>  1 ABW   Aruba                Aruba Aruba               
#>  2 AFG   Afghanistan          Aruba Afghanistan         
#>  3 AGO   Angola               Aruba Angola              
#>  4 AIA   Anguilla             Aruba Anguilla            
#>  5 ALB   Albania              Aruba Albania             
#>  6 AND   Andorra              Aruba Andorra             
#>  7 ANT   Netherland Antilles  Aruba Netherland Antilles 
#>  8 ARE   United Arab Emirates Aruba United Arab Emirates
#>  9 ARG   Argentina            Aruba Argentina           
#> 10 ARM   Armenia              Aruba Armenia
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Some base R solutions:

```r
df <- structure(list(code = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND",  "ANT", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM"), country = c("Aruba", "Afghanistan",  "Angola", "Anguilla", "Albania", "Andorra", "Netherland Antilles",  "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia"), iso_o = c("ABW",  "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW", "ABW" ), iso_d = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT",  "ARE", "ARG", "ARM")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

# create a "lookup_df" dataframe
lookup_df <- df[,1:2]

# base match using lookup dataframe
df2 <- df
tochange <- match(df2$iso_o, lookup_df$code, nomatch = 0)
df2$iso_o[tochange > 0] <- lookup_df$country[tochange]
tochange2 <- match(df2$iso_d, lookup_df$code, nomatch = 0)
df2$iso_d[tochange2 > 0] <- lookup_df$country[tochange2]
df2
#>    code              country iso_o                iso_d
#> 1   ABW                Aruba Aruba                Aruba
#> 2   AFG          Afghanistan Aruba          Afghanistan
#> 3   AGO               Angola Aruba               Angola
#> 4   AIA             Anguilla Aruba             Anguilla
#> 5   ALB              Albania Aruba              Albania
#> 6   AND              Andorra Aruba              Andorra
#> 7   ANT  Netherland Antilles Aruba  Netherland Antilles
#> 8   ARE United Arab Emirates Aruba United Arab Emirates
#> 9   ARG            Argentina Aruba            Argentina
#> 10  ARM              Armenia Aruba              Armenia

# base for loop using lookup dataframe
df2 <- df
for (i in seq_len(nrow(lookup_df))) {
  df2$iso_d[df$iso_d == lookup_df$code[i]] = lookup_df$country[i]
  df2$iso_o[df$iso_o == lookup_df$code[i]] = lookup_df$country[i]
}
df2
#>    code              country iso_o                iso_d
#> 1   ABW                Aruba Aruba                Aruba
#> 2   AFG          Afghanistan Aruba          Afghanistan
#> 3   AGO               Angola Aruba               Angola
#> 4   AIA             Anguilla Aruba             Anguilla
#> 5   ALB              Albania Aruba              Albania
#> 6   AND              Andorra Aruba              Andorra
#> 7   ANT  Netherland Antilles Aruba  Netherland Antilles
#> 8   ARE United Arab Emirates Aruba United Arab Emirates
#> 9   ARG            Argentina Aruba            Argentina
#> 10  ARM              Armenia Aruba              Armenia
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>